How to write a dynamic SQL query using PIVOT function on a date column
Requirement: to create a pivot table which will show output like this:

My PL/SQL block looks like this:
DECLARE
    v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_months VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    -- Generate the list of months dynamically for the pivot clause
    FOR i IN 0..11 LOOP
        v_months := v_months ||''''|| TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, i), 'MonYYYY') || ''', ';
    END LOOP;

    -- Remove the trailing comma and space
    v_months := RTRIM(v_months, ', ');

    -- Construct the dynamic SQL for creating the table
    v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE dynamic_pivot_table_test AS ' ||
             'SELECT * FROM (' ||
             'SELECT part, TO_CHAR(begin_date, ''MonYYYY'') AS begin_date_YM, SUM(new_buy_units) AS SUM_UNITS ' ||
             'FROM one_mpbr ' ||
             'WHERE begin_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, ''MM'') ' ||
             'AND begin_date < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, ''MM''), 12) ' ||
             'GROUP BY part, TO_CHAR(begin_date, ''MonYYYY'')) ' ||
             'PIVOT (SUM(SUM_UNITS) FOR begin_date_YM IN (' || v_months || '))';

    -- Print the dynamic SQL query
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL query to create the table
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/

Problem: this code is producing dynamic columns enclosed in single quotation mark as shown in the screenshot here:

I have to remove this mark also would be helpful if I can get Grand total column as well.

You need to alias your columns, e.g. in the PIVOT part, it needs to be:
begin_date_ym IN('May2024' AS "May2024",
                 'Jun2024' AS "Jun2024",
                 ...)

which you can do by amending your procedure to include the alias:
v_months := v_months ||''''|| TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, i), 'MonYYYY') ||
                       ''' AS "' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, i), 'MonYYYY') || '", ';

See this db<>fiddle for an example

Thank you, this solution helped me to get the desired column name. However it disturbed the calculation of these dynamic fields. The sum of units in the months are coming different and this shows different although the sum of months columns values are same.

There isn't enough information in your question for us to help you. If you are seeing an issue with the figures, you need to provide us with a minimal test case that includes all the information that demonstrates the information that we can run ourselves. I don't see how adding an alias to the columns could possibly change the data being returned by them - the output in my db<>fiddle doesn't change with or without the column aliases
